# Android: Java cannot refer to a non-final variable

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener, final

In my `Android` application, when the users click on `Sales` button, it will show another view to perform the sales.

My application is working without having any problems before I have implemented an alert dialog to display a warning message to users if GST License expiry date of selected customer is less than 7 days and going to expire soon. Now I am getting the following error message if I don't declare `final` to these two variables, `customer` and `v`.

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable `customer` inside an inner class defined in a different method
>
> Cannot refer to a non-final variable `v` inside an inner class defined in a different method

I understand that

> The reference declared as final cannot be modified once it is
>   initialized.

So, what will happen if I assign these two variables as `final`? It always contain the same value? Can someone please explain to me why the compiler giving me these errors and why I should declare `final` to these two variables?

Here is my source code:

```
private OnClickListener salesBtnClick = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Customer customer = salesCustAdpt.getSelectedCustomer();
        if (customer != null) {                                
            Date expiryDate = customer.getGSTLicenseExpiryDate();
            if (checkCustomerGSTLicenseExpiryDate(expiryDate)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SalesCustomerActivity.this);
                builder.setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(
                        "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                try {
                                    //Perform sales here!
                                    Intent intent = null;
                                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SalesActivity.class);//Error msg here!
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putSerializable("selCustomer", customer);//Error msg here!
                                    intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    AddPlusUtil.displayErrorMsg(
                                                    SalesCustomerActivity.this,
                                                    ex);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.setTitle("Warning Message");
                String errMsg = "GST License Expiry Date of selected customer is \n" + expiryDate + " and going to expire soon.";
                alert.setMessage(errMsg);
                alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error);
                alert.show();
            } else {
                //Perform Sales
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining Customer, use final:

```
final Customer customer = salesCustAdpt.getSelectedCustomer();
```

Also, in your onClick method, set the View as final:

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, this will solve my problem but will there be any other problems if I declare `final` to both of them?

Comment: if you declare a variable as final, you can't give the variable a new reference, but that shouldn't be a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Define that `customer` and  `v` globally in your class. It will resolve the issue.

Create one global view object than assign it with your `v`

```
globalView = v;
```

and use that globalView for calling intent.

and by the way you can use `yourClass.this` as context instead of your view context.

Comment: v is an object of View class in this line of code, `public void onClick(View v) {}`. How can I declare it globally?

Comment: if you using view in on click method only than it will not the issue to use final for that. onclick is overrided method.